# Incorrect date when formatting

Tags: angularjs

I have the following date 2017-09-04 and when I try to format it to dd / mm / yyyy I get the date 03 / 09-2017

```
<select id="diaInstalacion" ng-model="view.diaInstalcion" tabindex="1" class="select-input" ng-options="schedule as (schedule.date | date:'DD/MM/YYYY' : 'UTC') + ' ' + schedule.startHour + '-' + schedule.endHour + ' ' + schedule.timeSlot for schedule in schedules" required>
       <option selected value="">- Seleccione -</option>      
</select>
```

Also, when I try `new Date('2017-09-04')` I get one less day and I do not understand why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Comment: What browser are you using?